# ASP.NET core Web API routing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

1. Route using "UseMvc" but not able to call the controller
2. In startup page have added `service.AddMvc` method & in configure section it's `app.useMvc()`
3. I am not able to route and can't figure out what the problem is

The controller code is here and have route : the action method is `Get` with parameter `start` of `DateTime` type

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CurrencyContext>(cfg => {
                  cfg.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("BitCoinIndexConnectionString"));
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseNodeModules(env);

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
                      {             
                          routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
                                          template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{start:DateTime}",
                                          defaults: new { 
                                                            controller = "Currency", 
                                                            action = "Get", 
                                                            start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)});                          
                                                        });
                      }
}

[Route("api/[Controller]")]
public class CurrencyController : Controller
{
    private BitCoinRepository<BitCoinIndex> _repository;

    public CurrencyController(BitCoinRepository<BitCoinIndex> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet("{start}",Name ="Get")]
    public IActionResult Get(DateTime start)
    {
        // var bci =  _repository.GetByDates(start).ToDictionary(t => t.Date.ToString(), t => t.Rate);
        return View();    
    }
}
```

Comment: read this first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/

Comment: @Priyanka Should i change my answer to match your latest edit?

Comment: @AbdulG Yeah, because the application version is ASP.NET core 2.2 & doesn't contain definition of EnableEndpointRouting.

Comment: Edited the answer, try it now.

Comment: Don't add route to routing table inside `Configure` method

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it using attribute routing. This is what I did. If you are not using .Net Core 3, ignore point 1.

1st disable endpoint routing by adding this in your `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

You can now use this in `Configure` method

```
app.UseMvc();
```

Next, just define your routes inside the controller (bear in mind I generally prefer routing by adding routes to the routing table, but encountered unnecassary issues going this 'route', attribute routing was the easiest 'route' to take).

```
[Route("api/myctrl")]
[ApiController]
public class MyControllerController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getsomething")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> DoStuff()
    {

    }

}
```

Access this by either using `@Url.Action("DoStuff", "MyController");` or `/api/myctrl/getsomething`

Comment: The application is ASP.NET CORE 2.2 & does not contain definition for Mvc options options.EnableEndpointRouting

Comment: Yes, its from .net core 3. Not a problem, in that case ignore that point.